# Import excel worksheet to active sheet

Tags: vba, excel, import

I have invoice with lots of Data. I want to Export and import data. I have created Export VBA that exports particular sheet ("Invoice Data"). I have saved it somewhere. Now I need to import that same file into active worksheet.

I have this code

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ASheet As Worksheet

'Turns off screenupdating and events:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Sets the variables:
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(WB.Path & "\1.xlsx")  'Modify to match

'Copies each sheet of the SourceWB to the end of original wb:
For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
Next WS

    SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing

WB.Activate
ASheet.Select
    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

this code works pretty well. but i want to choose the file with file open dialog

Anyone help me please

Comment: You did not provide any informations, tell us: How do you export. What do you export. Format of the exported. There should it be imported and has it the same structure ? Where do you saved it and everything else. At the moment your question is just: How do I import something from somewhere inside of something.

Comment: Oh.. sorry.. now let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the code....

```
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(fileStr)

wbk2.Sheets("invoice data").Copy After:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
```

thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

if your question is about.. how to use File open dialog.. you can use this code

```
    NewWorkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename( _  
            FileFilter:="Excel 2003 (*.xls),*.xls,Excel 2007 (*.xlsx),*.xlsx,Excel 2007 (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _  
            Title:="Select an Excel File", _  
            MultiSelect:=File)  
    If NewWorkbook = False Then  
        Exit Sub  
    Else  
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=NewWorkbook  
    End If
```

You can remove filters if you want to select any kind of files

Comment: It just open the file.. but i need to copy the sheet into active sheet